# how to write a code to skip a rising edge and continue the count till second rising edge is detected in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

I need to design a system to skip a particular rising edge and continue counting until next rising edge is detected ,as the next rising edge is detected it should start counting from zero.val1,val2,val3 have counts of different pulse which com from the external field.this pulse train repeats .
I leave the first pulse to count each pulse and the second pulse train is detected if the count is greater than the count or less than the count it should skip the rising edge and move to the next rising edge and start counting.
I have tried this way ..

```
library ieee; 
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; 
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all; 
use IEEE.Numeric_Std.all;
library work;
use work.all;

--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;



entity nxt_pwm is
  Port (  i_clk : in std_logic;
           signal_in: in std_logic;
            signal_in1: in std_logic;
        pwm_out: out std_logic);
end nxt_pwm;

architecture Behavioral of nxt_pwm is
  signal Q1,Q2,Q3 : unsigned(15 downto 0);

  signal reset,flag1,flag2,flag3,flag4: std_logic;
  signal val1,val2,val3:unsigned (15 downto 0); 
  signal cnt_f,count_q: unsigned (15 downto 0);
  signal  val_tot: unsigned (15 downto 0) ; 

begin
pulse_count:entity work.pulse port map(i_clk=>i_clk,signal_in1=>signal_in1,pwm_out=>pwm_out);

 uut3:   process (signal_in)
    --- variable    count_q : unsigned  (15 downto 0);
   --  variable reset: std_logic;   
           --  variable val_tot: unsigned (15 downto 0) ;              

                           begin
                           if rising_edge(signal_in) then
                           if (flag1 = '1') then
                            Q1 <= val2;

                            elsif (flag2 = '1') then
                             Q2 <= val1;

                             elsif (flag3 = '1') then
                            Q3 <= val3;

                            end if;



                            if (reset = '1') then
                            count_q <= "0000000000000000";
                           if (flag1 = '1') then
                           count_q <= val2;
                           count_q <= count_q - 1;      
                           if (signal_in'event and signal_in = '1') then
                            -- count_q <= count_q - 1;
                            end if;
                            elsif (flag2='1') then
                            count_q<=val1;
                            count_q <=count_q - 1;
                             if reset='0' then
                             if (signal_in'event and signal_in = '1') then
                                    -- count_q<= count_q -1 ;
                                  reset<='1';
                                  if (signal_in'event and signal_in = '1') then
                                  count_q<="0000";
                                  end if;
                  end if;
                  end if;                
                              elsif (flag3='1') then
                              count_q <=val3;
                           count_q <= count_q - 1;      
                           if (signal_in'event and signal_in = '1') then
                              flag1<='1';
                            end if;
                  end if;
                  end if;
                  end if;          

                          end process;

    UUT2:  process (i_clk,signal_in)
     begin


                             if rising_edge(signal_in) then
                             if flag1<='1' or flag2<='1' or flag3<='1' then
                            if (cnt_f /= val_tot)then
                            if (cnt_f< (val_tot/2)) then
                            pwm_out<='1';
                            else
                            pwm_out<='0';
                            end if;
                            cnt_f<=cnt_f+1;
                            end if;
                            end if;
                            END IF;
                        end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: You need to think how you would solve this in hardware before coding in VHDL. I would think (without thinking about it too much) that you would need a _synchronous edge detector_ (Google it), a _counter_ and perhaps a simple _finite state machine_ to control the counter. Draw a block diagram of how they could be connected up. Then write your VHDL. And before you do, find out how to do combinational and sequential logic in VHDL.

Comment: The structure IF RISING_EDGE ... IF RESET is not well formed and way occur on errors depending on your synthesis tool.

For your problem, you can for example develop a counter process with a signal "increment" as an input. When increment = '1', you can effectively increment your counter. Then, you build an FSM where a single cycle State desassert this signal.